# Merge (and split) 2 different LAN in one Cable with VLAN?

Tags: vlan, lan

I am searching for a way to connect two different buildings with one GB Ethernet Cable.
On both LAN i have two different routers with different subnets that needs to be remain in the new building.
The reason is that one LAN is to be used for VOIP and has its own router and internet connection.

Now the question: Is this somehow can be done with 2 VLAN switches ? Can i combine the 2 LANs into one output and split on the other end again?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: If you want more than a simple Yes/No answer (those types of question are really not suitable for SE sites), then you need to provide more details, such as a good network description or diagram, the network device models, and the network device configurations. The general answer is that yes, you _may_ be able to do that, but it depends on your network.

Comment: Yes, it can....